Configuring a Ros2 c++ project in Vscode
It's been 1 week that I'm trying to figure out how to configure correctly my ros2 c++ pkg on visual code studio. I've generate a c++ package with this command :
ros2 pkg create \
 --build-type ament_cmake \
 --dependencies moveit_ros_planning_interface rclcpp \
 --node-name manager sr_manager

In the manager.cpp, I've write this very basic code :
#include <memory>

#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  // Initialize ROS and create the Node
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  auto const node = std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>(
    "hello_moveit",
    rclcpp::NodeOptions().automatically_declare_parameters_from_overrides(true)
  );

  // Create a ROS logger
  auto const logger = rclcpp::get_logger("hello_moveit");

  // Next step goes here

  // Shutdown ROS
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}

However, I'm still getting the same error again and again : rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp: No such file or directory.
I can't understand what is wrong, what I'm supposed to do more to just include a basic header. Here are my CmakeList and package.xml
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(sr_manager)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(moveit_ros_planning_interface REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)

add_executable(manager src/manager.cpp)
target_include_directories(manager PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)
target_compile_features(manager PUBLIC c_std_99 cxx_std_17)  # Require C99 and C++17
ament_target_dependencies(
  manager
  "moveit_ros_planning_interface"
  "rclcpp"
)

install(TARGETS manager
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # comment the line when a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # comment the line when this package is in a git repo and when
  # a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()


package.xml :
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>sr_manager</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="">luca</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

  <depend>moveit_ros_planning_interface</depend>
  <depend>rclcpp</depend>

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>


Moreover, I think this file is also very important to make everything work :
c_cpp_properties.json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "ROS2 Workspace",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",   // All source headers
                "/opt/ros/humble/include/**",              // ROS 2 standard headers
                "/usr/include/**",                         // System headers
                "/usr/include/eigen3",                     // Eigen for MoveIt2
                "/home/luca/ros2_ws/smart_robot/install/sr_manager/**",   // Custom headers
                "/home/luca/ros2_ws/smart_robot/src/sr_manager/include/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

Some help would be much appreciated, ty !

ty for your answer !
ros2 pkg list | grep rclcpp
examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client
examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server
examples_rclcpp_minimal_client
examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition
examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher
examples_rclcpp_minimal_service
examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber
examples_rclcpp_minimal_timer
examples_rclcpp_multithreaded_executor
rclcpp
rclcpp_action
rclcpp_components
rclcpp_lifecycle

and
ls /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp 

So this should not be a ros installtion problem. However there is an extra rclcpp directory as you see. I've try to write instead :
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>

but have the same error rclcpp/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp: No such file or directory
Some extra information
Config

Ubuntu 22.04
ROS2 Humble

Extensions install in Vscode

Python
C/C++
CMake/CMakeTools
ROS
ROS2


I tried to reproduce the issue using the steps you described, but I couldn’t. Everything worked without issues. However, I’d like to clarify something important first:
The error rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp: No such file or directory can't be resolved by configuring c_cpp_properties.json alone. This file is used by VSCode’s intellisense to recognize header files and provide auto-completion, making development easier. This file does not affect the build process. Even if intellisense can locate rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp header, the compiler must also be able to find it during the build process.
The problem may be your ROS installation has problems. To check, run the command:
ros2 pkg list | grep rclcpp

You should see rclcpp listed in the output. If it’s missing, this confirms a problem with your installation.
You can also verify that the rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp file exists by running:
ls /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/include/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp

If the file doesn’t exist, your ROS installation is corrupted.
If this is the case, you will need to reinstall ROS2. Start by removing the current installation:
sudo apt remove ros-humble-* && sudo apt autoremove #change humble to your distro
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

Then, reinstall ROS2:
sudo apt install ros-humble-desktop #change humble to your distro

Finally, source the setup file:
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash

After re-installing ROS, start clean by creating a new workspace and try your steps again. Please let me know if this resolves your problem.
